# Encode all user input to prevent rXSS

Tags: java, security, xss

I am trying to solve a security vulnerability to prevent xss.

Should I encode all user input such as <> tags before storing into the database, or I should store the raw input into the database and only encode for HTML upon retriving the data from database and display on HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reflected XSS refers to an attack when the script is not stored, it is shown to the client the same input. Example, in a search you enter the name, and the answer of the system is "name not found." in this case you can put an script instead of the name.

If you want to store the input to be read it later. It is known as stored XSS. How do you can prevent it ? It's a difficult part. You can use white list validation. If your input is HTML you can use  OWASP_Java_HTML_Sanitizer_Project https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Java_HTML_Sanitizer_Project

When do you need to use the enconding? You need to enconde the data based on the context where it will be used. For example if you need to present the data on a HTML page, you need to encode HTML before showing the data. But if you need to use it on a JS script you need to use URL enconde. The enconde depends on the context where you use the data.

Comment: in this case, I should only encode when I need to display the data, not when I am storing it into the database ?

Comment: Yes, because you can use the data in different systems. Probably to execute a command or to display on a web page. You need to encode the data depending on the system that will use it.